# Control holomonic robot position XY and orientation with 3 PID

Tags: pid, wheeled-robot

I'm really new in robotic field trying to learn new stuff. I have a holomonic robot (with 3 omniwheels) that i wan't to move around. I already have a lidar that gives the XY robot position and it's orientation.

Now my goal is to give the robot a position goal and make it reach that position.

I plan to use 3 PIDs for each components (1 for x position, 1 for y position and 1 for orientation).

Do you consider this as a good solution or there is another better solution ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* AC3, but I'm afraid that opinion polls are [discouraged on stack exchange](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/). We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of advantages & disadvantages for different options are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: If it's a holonomic system, do you need the PID controllers at all? Can you actuate based on position differences? A recurring phrase in software engineering is "don't prematurely optimize." Try to get some minimum viable product finished and then you can start evaluating system performance and try to determine where you can improve.